# System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing

Tags: apex, unit-test, dml

Can any one help me out with this error :

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [OpportunityId]: [OpportunityId] 
>       Class.TestCreateSubscriptionOpptyClone.TestCreateSubscription: line 58, column 1
>       line 58 is :insert opptyConRolelist;

All the mandatory fields are added in the test code but it still throws an error.

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class TestCreateSubscriptionOpptyClone 
{

static testMethod void TestCreateSubscription()
{
//Create Account 

Account acc1 = new Account();
acc1.Name='Testing SubscriptionClone';
acc1.BillingStreet='Banjara hills';
acc1.BillingCity='Hyd';
acc1.BillingState='TS';
acc1.BillingPostalCode = '500084';
acc1.BillingCountry = 'India';
acc1.Phone = '100';
acc1.Industry = 'Banking';         
acc1.Type = 'Paid';
acc1.Customer_Type__c = 'Customer';
acc1.Customer_List__c = true;
insert acc1 ;

//Create Contact

contact cc = new contact();
cc.FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription';
cc.LastName ='Opptyclone';
cc.Role__c='Subscription Administrator';
cc.AccountId=acc1.Id;
insert cc;

//Create Opportunity

Opportunity opty = new Opportunity();
opty.Name = 'Test SubscriptionOppty';
opty.StageName ='Proposal/Price Quote';
opty.Probability =60;
opty.LeadSource = 'Subscription Renewal';
opty.CloseDate = System.Today();                
opty.Type = 'Existing Customer';
opty.Assigned_Sales_Engineer__c = null;
opty.Payment_Type__c = 'Order Form';
opty.Update_Complete__c = true;
opty.Partner__c = 'None';
opty.Anchor__c='Non Anchor';
opty.AccountId = acc1.Id;
opty.StageName = 'Closed Won';
//insert opty;

//Create Opportunity Contact Role 
 list<OpportunityContactRole> opptyConRolelist =  new list<OpportunityContactRole>();   
OpportunityContactRole opptyConRole =  new OpportunityContactRole();   
opptyConRole.ContactId = cc.Id;
opptyConRole.OpportunityId = opty.Id;   
opptyConRole.IsPrimary = false;
opptyConRole.Role = 'Subscription Administrator';
opptyConRolelist.add(opptyConRole);
insert opptyConRolelist;

 opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
 opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  false;
 update opty;

//Add oppty line items
  string stdpdId = '01s500000001e6k';
//Create OpportunityLineitem 

 List<OpportunityLineItem> ooliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

//Create Product

product2 p2 = new product2();
p2.Name ='Postgres Plus Enterprise Edition Unicores';
p2.Product_Name1__C='Product - Subscription';
p2.Product_Group__c='PPAS';
p2.IsActive = true;
p2.Description='Postgres Plus Enterprise Edition Unicores';

insert p2;

//Create PriceBookEntry 

PricebookEntry pbey = new PricebookEntry();
 pbey.Product2ID=p2.id;
 pbey.Pricebook2ID=stdpdId;
 pbey.UnitPrice=50; 
 pbey.isActive=true;
insert pbey;

Opportunitylineitem ooli = new Opportunitylineitem();
ooli.OpportunityId = opty.Id;    
ooli.PricebookEntryId = pbey.Id;
ooli.Quantity =4;
//ooli.Product_Code__c='PREE-UCC-001';
//ooli.Unit_of_Measure__c='Unicore';
ooli.Start_Date__c = System.today();
ooli.End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100;
ooli.Type_of_Contract__c='None';
ooli.Term__c =12;
ooli.Type_Of_Product__c='Single Year Subscription';
ooli.Type_of_ARR__c= 'New Addition ARR';
ooliList.add(ooli);
insert ooliList;

opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = true;
update opty;

 opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
 opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  false;
 update opty;

 //Create Product

product2 pr2 = new product2();
pr2.Name ='Postgres Plus Standard Edition Unicores';
pr2.Product_Name1__C='Product - Subscription';
pr2.Product_Group__c='PPAS';
pr2.IsActive = true;
pr2.Description='Postgres Plus Standard Edition Unicores';

insert pr2;

//Create PriceBookEntry 

PricebookEntry pbety = new PricebookEntry();
 pbety.Product2ID=pr2.id;
 pbety.Pricebook2ID=stdpdId;
 pbety.UnitPrice=50; 
 pbety.isActive=true;
insert pbety;

Opportunitylineitem ooli1 = new Opportunitylineitem();
ooli1.OpportunityId = opty.Id;    
ooli1.PricebookEntryId = pbety.Id;
ooli1.Quantity =4;
//ooli.Product_Code__c='PREE-UCC-001';
//ooli.Unit_of_Measure__c='Unicore';
ooli1.Start_Date__c = System.today();
ooli1.End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100;
ooli1.Type_of_Contract__c='None';
ooli1.Term__c =12;
ooli1.Type_Of_Product__c='Single Year Subscription';
ooli1.Type_of_ARR__c= 'New Addition ARR';
ooliList.add(ooli1);
insert ooliList;

opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = true;
update opty;

 opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
 opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  false;
 update opty;


 //update contact roles - to test the subscription product type
        for(OpportunityContactRole r1: opptyConRolelist)
        {
            r1.Role = 'Subscription Administrator';                                              
        }
        update opptyConRolelist;                
        opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = true;                
        update opty;               

        opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
        opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  true;
        update opty;

        opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c =  true;           
        update opty;  

}
static testMethod void TestCreateSubscription1()
{
//Create Account 

Account acc1 = new Account();
acc1.Name='Testing SubscriptionClone';
acc1.BillingStreet='Banjara hills';
acc1.BillingCity='Hyd';
acc1.BillingState='TS';
acc1.BillingPostalCode = '500084';
acc1.BillingCountry = 'India';
acc1.Phone = '100';
acc1.Industry = 'Banking';         
acc1.Type = 'Paid';
acc1.Customer_Type__c = 'Customer';
acc1.Customer_List__c = true;
insert acc1 ;

//Create Contact

contact cc = new contact();
cc.FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription';
cc.LastName ='Opptyclone';
cc.Role__c='Subscription Administrator';
cc.AccountId=acc1.Id;
insert cc;

//Create Opportunity

Opportunity opty = new Opportunity();
opty.Name = 'Test SubscriptionOppty';
opty.StageName ='Stage 4:Proposal Delivery';
opty.Probability =60;
opty.LeadSource = 'Subscription Renewal';
opty.CloseDate = System.Today();                
opty.Type = 'Existing Customer';
opty.Assigned_Sales_Engineer__c = null;
opty.Payment_Type__c = 'Order Form';
opty.Partner__c = 'None';
opty.Anchor__c='Non Anchor';
opty.Update_Complete__c = true;
opty.AccountId = acc1.Id;
//opty.StageName = 'Closed Won';
//insert opty;

//Create Opportunity Contact Role 
 list<OpportunityContactRole> opptyConRolelist =  new list<OpportunityContactRole>();   
OpportunityContactRole opptyConRole =  new OpportunityContactRole();   
opptyConRole.ContactId = cc.Id;
opptyConRole.OpportunityId = opty.Id;   
opptyConRole.IsPrimary = false;
opptyConRole.Role = 'Subscription Administrator';
opptyConRolelist.add(opptyConRole);
insert opptyConRolelist;

 opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
 opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  false;
 update opty;

//Add oppty line items
  string stdpdId = '01s500000001e6k';
//Create OpportunityLineitem 

 List<OpportunityLineItem> ooliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

//Create Product

product2 p2 = new product2();
p2.Name ='Postgres Plus Enterprise Edition Unicores';
p2.Product_Name1__C='Product - Subscription';
p2.Product_Group__c='PPAS';
p2.IsActive = true;
p2.Description='Postgres Plus Enterprise Edition Unicores';

insert p2;

//Create PriceBookEntry 

PricebookEntry pbey = new PricebookEntry();
 pbey.Product2ID=p2.id;
 pbey.Pricebook2ID=stdpdId;
 pbey.UnitPrice=50; 
 pbey.isActive=true;
insert pbey;

Opportunitylineitem ooli = new Opportunitylineitem();
ooli.OpportunityId = opty.Id;    
ooli.PricebookEntryId = pbey.Id;
ooli.Quantity =4;
//ooli.Product_Code__c='PREE-UCC-001';
//ooli.Unit_of_Measure__c='Unicore';
ooli.Start_Date__c = System.today();
ooli.End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100;
ooli.Type_of_Contract__c='None';
ooli.Term__c =12;
ooli.Type_Of_Product__c='Single Year Subscription';
ooli.Type_of_ARR__c= 'New Addition ARR';
ooliList.add(ooli);
insert ooliList;

opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = true;
update opty;

 opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
 opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  false;
 update opty;

 //Create Product

product2 pr2 = new product2();
pr2.Name ='Postgres Plus Standard Edition Unicores';
pr2.Product_Name1__C='Product - Subscription';
pr2.Product_Group__c='PPAS';
pr2.IsActive = true;
pr2.Description='Postgres Plus Standard Edition Unicores';

insert pr2;

//Create PriceBookEntry 

PricebookEntry pbety = new PricebookEntry();
 pbety.Product2ID=pr2.id;
 pbety.Pricebook2ID=stdpdId;
 pbety.UnitPrice=50; 
 pbety.isActive=true;
insert pbety;

Opportunitylineitem ooli1 = new Opportunitylineitem();
ooli1.OpportunityId = opty.Id;    
ooli1.PricebookEntryId = pbety.Id;
ooli1.Quantity =4;
//ooli.Product_Code__c='PREE-UCC-001';
//ooli.Unit_of_Measure__c='Unicore';
ooli1.Start_Date__c = System.today();
ooli1.End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100;
ooli1.Type_of_Contract__c='None';
ooli1.Term__c =12;
ooli1.Type_Of_Product__c='Single Year Subscription';
ooli1.Type_of_ARR__c= 'New Addition ARR';
ooliList.add(ooli1);
insert ooliList;

opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = true;
update opty;

 opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
 opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  false;
 update opty;


 //update contact roles - to test the subscription product type
        for(OpportunityContactRole r1: opptyConRolelist)
        {
            r1.Role = 'Subscription Administrator';                                              
        }
        update opptyConRolelist;                
        opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = true;                
        update opty;               

        opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c = false;
        opty.Contracts_Processed__c =  true;
        update opty;

        opty.UPDATE_COMPLETE__c =  true;           
        update opty;  

}
}
```

Comment: OpportunityId is null at that point - opptyConRolelist, you havent inserted **opty**

Comment: Do yourself (and other SE users) a favour and extract your object creation to methods. It's not easy to debug a 100+ line method, especially when you have no line numbering

Answer (score 3):

Why insert opty is commented ? // Might be you are in middle of debugging and forgot to uncomment it

```
Opportunity opty = new Opportunity();
opty.Name = 'Test SubscriptionOppty';
opty.StageName ='Proposal/Price Quote';
opty.Probability =60;
opty.LeadSource = 'Subscription Renewal';
opty.CloseDate = System.Today();                
opty.Type = 'Existing Customer';
opty.Assigned_Sales_Engineer__c = null;
opty.Payment_Type__c = 'Order Form';
opty.Update_Complete__c = true;
opty.Partner__c = 'None';
opty.Anchor__c='Non Anchor';
opty.AccountId = acc1.Id;
opty.StageName = 'Closed Won';
//insert opty;
```

I think opty doesn't have an Id since it is not inserted into db and hence the error.

Please remove the comment from below line and test

**//insert opty;**

Comment: :Thanks for your response.When i insert the opportunity ,system started throwing an error as :System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Channelinsight.CI_SFOpportunityTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Channelinsight.CI_OpportunityTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert
caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
(Channelinsight)

Comment: Channelinsight might be some custom object coming from a Managed package and the code internally assumes there will be atleast one Channelinsight. I am not sure about the code but I think it will be like `List<Channelinsight> channelInsight  = [Select Id from ChannelInsight];` but its not returning anything. Can you verify the initial set of Channelinsight data required for your org ?